# Two Multivariable Limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to solve the following limit:$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot(1+\ln(x^2+y^2))}$$. I expect for it to be $0$, but not sure how to prove it. I tought using a substitution $t=x^2+y^2$ but not sure what to do with part $x+y$. Also i tried comparing this to get that $0\le f(x,y)\le 0$.

Comment: $\ln(1+t)\sim t$ ($t\to 0$).

Answer (score 4):

$|x+y| \leq \sqrt 2 \sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$. So $0 \leq |f(x,y)| \leq \frac {\sqrt 2 t} {t(1+2\ln t)}$ where $t =\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$.  Now use the fact that $\ln t \to -\infty$ as $t \to 0+$.

Comment: Stupid question, but how did you get that $|x+y|\le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: $(x+y)^{2} \leq 2 (x^{2}+y^{2})$ take square root. It is also a special case of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. @Trevor